# Do I need RD Gateway for one Windows server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds

I am running one Windows Server on EC2 and have 6 users who will be using remote desktop to login to it and work remotely.

Is native RDP security sufficient for this or is it critical to install/configure RDGateway with just the single session host?

Answer (score 0):

RD Gateway really only helps multiple backend RDP servers, and when accessing those servers from a multitude of devices.  PC, laptop, tablet, chromebook, Android, etc.